# Update multiple fields using Firebase React Native Hooks

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I want to update multiple fields from user input data using useState, but I can't seem to find any example for that.

```
const [productName, setProductName] = useState(props.route.params.productName)
const [caption, setCaption] = useState(props.route.params.category)
const [category, setCategory] = useState(props.route.params.caption)
const [receiveDate, setReceiveDate] = useState(props.route.params.receiveDate)
const [expiryDate, setExpiryDate] = useState(props.route.params.expiryDate)

const updatePostData = (userId, productName, caption, category, receiveDate) => {
      firebase.firestore()
            .collection('posts')
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .doc(userId)
            .update({
                  productName,
                  caption,
                  category,
                  receiveDate
                  expiryDate
              })
            .then(() => 
                setProductName(""), setCaption(""), setCategory(""), 
                setReceiveDate(""), setExpiryDate(""))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error)); 
}

useEffect(() => {
      setProductName(productName), 
      setCaption(caption),
      setCategory(category),
      setReceiveDate(receiveDate),
      setExpiryDate(expiryDate);
      console.log("useEffect passes the currentItem: ", 
      {productName, caption, category, receiveDate, expiryDate});
    }, []);

<TextInput 
    placeholder="Product name"
    onChangeText={(productName) => setProductName(productName)}           
/> //same for other input

<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => updatePostData(productName, caption, category, receiveDate, expiryDate)} >
    <Text>UPDATE</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I get this error.

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: undefined

Do I need save all fields in one new const? Or should I convert them to object? How?

Comment: Are you sure that all those variables have a value? Can you check that pls with a console.log

Comment: Yes, I have check with console.log, and successfully return all value from useEffect. Or do you see any possible problem there?

Comment: But from console.log(error) after I click the button, I get this -> FirebaseError: Requested entity was not found.

Comment: That error sounds like the document you're trying to update doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

`.update()` expects an object with `key:value` pairs.  You have created an object with just values- no keys.

I suspect you want:

```
.update({
  "productName": productName,
  "caption": caption,
  "category": category,
  "receiveDate": receiveDate
  "expiryDate": expiryDate
 })
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But do you know how to call the doc id? It is undefined, so it's getting error.

Comment: Which doc Id?  Do you mean the userId?  I suspect that might be, as said above, because the document doesn't exist yet - and ```.update()``` will fail if the document doesn't already exist.  On the other hand, you *could* use ```.set()``` with ```mergeOption:true```, which will do much the same thing, but create the document if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I have tried .set() with mergeOption:true, but it will override other document as well. Do you know how to call the generated id, to replace userId? Do I have to use .push( ) to get the id?

Comment: Since you don't SHOW anything about a "generated id", I have absolutely no idea WHAT you are talking about, alas.